# Unable to capture required string from text file using Groovy - Jmeter JSR223

Tags: regex, groovy, jmeter, jsr223

I need to parse a text file testresults.txt and capture serial number and then write the captured serial number onto separate text file called serialno.txt using groovy Jmeter JSR223 post processor.
Below code is not working. It didn't get into the while loop itself. Kindly help.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern
import java.util.regex.Matcher

String filecontent = new File("C:/device/resources/testresults.txt").text

def regex = "SerialNumber\" value=\"(.+)\""

java.util.regex.Pattern p = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(regex)
java.util.regex.Matcher m = p.matcher(filecontent)

File SN = new File("C:/device/resources/serialno.txt")

while(m.find()) {
     SN.write m.group(1) 
}
```

Comment: Without the actual input, we can't help you debug the issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your code doesn't enter the loop it means that there are no matches so you need to amend your regular expression, you can use i.e. [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) website for experiments

Given the following content of the `testresults.txt` file:

```
SerialNumber" value="foo"
SerialNumber" value="bar"
SerialNumber" value="baz"
```

your code works fine.

For the time being I can only suggest using [match operator](https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_match_operator) to make your code more "groovy"

```
def source = new File('C:/device/resources/testresults.txt').text

def matches = (source =~ 'SerialNumber" value="(.+?)"')

matches.each { match ->
    new File('C:/device/resources/serialno.txt') << match[1] << System.getProperty('line.separator')
}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)